# Efficiency of my Java power method?

Tags: java, performance, math

So I went into a job interview and they asked me to write up a quick math power method on a white board and this is what I put up there

```
public static double pow(double base, double power) {
    double result = 1.0;
    for(double x = 0; x < power; x++) {
        result = result * base;
    }

    return result;
}
```

This worked and they were satisfied with it, but then proceeded to ask me how I could make it more efficient and i had no response.  So my question is, can you get more efficient than this or was that just a question to make me sweat a little bit?  I'm thinking that there could be some direct bit shifting solution but I'm not exactly sure, I think that would only apply for powers of 2?  Any ideas?

***EDIT**
Sorry I forgot to mention that that the method signature was given to me (the doubles as inputs) and i was told i could not use any built-in math libraries.

Comment: `result *= base;` is the first thing that springs to mind.

Comment: Not sure, probably something to do with recursion or dynamic programming?

Comment: @nickecarlo Recursion will be extra load work for this.

Comment: I don't know how much of a difference `result *= base` would make. And I don't think recursion would help either. Dynamic programming could be an alternative, if you find a smart way to implement it.

Comment: `int x = 0;` could be more efficient than `double x = 0;`

Comment: You could use `int` instead of `double` for `power` as your method wouldn't be able to calculate roots (i.e. pow(4, 0.5)), so there's no need for doubles...

Comment: @Smit LouisWasserman's example from Wikipedia suggests otherwise.

Comment: change power parameter to integer type.

Comment: @jlordo long will be much better than int

Comment: @Smit: if you're raising a number to a power that doesn't fit into an `int`, you're already pretty much screwed.  `double` can't handle numbers greater than 2^1024, and even if you're using a `BigInteger`, you'll start running low on memory pretty quickly.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: I'm only mentioning the loop counter in my comment..

Comment: edited my post to clarify i forgot that the method signature was given to me as a requirement

Comment: @nickecarlo I was talking about recursion specific.

Comment: @Smit I didn't give any specifics ;) I said "probably something to do with recursion" The Wikipedia link uses recursion.

Comment: @nickecarlo I apologize...PEACE OUT _V_

Comment: @Smit no need to apologize. We were just discussing :)

Comment: @RaymondHolguin Did you get the job?

Comment: @nickecarlo I did get an offer, but didn't accept as the salary wasn't quite what i was hoping for.

Answer (score 20):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring The "basic method" is O(log n), as opposed to this O(n) algorithm.  ([Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/math/IntMath.html#line.227) has a non-recursive implementation.)

Also, your power parameter should almost certainly be an `int`.  (If you really *want* to implement an algorithm to raise numbers to non-integer powers, you're going to need a lot more math.)

Comment: Well, you read my mind while I was writing my comment at the other side of the world.

Comment: edited my post to clarify i forgot that the method signature was given to me as a requirement.  Thanks for the wikipedia link , i will check it out

Answer (score 2):

Thinking outside the box a little bit, there is generally a tradeoff between memory and speed.  There is the concept of [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

You could add a static double[][] cache that stores the result for any particular value.

Something like:

```
// look for the value in the cache, if it is there return it.

for(double x = 0; x < power; x++) {
    result = result * base;
    // store result in the cache
}
```

This would work, but would use a lot of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying the answer against itself and other determined multiples can yield you with different powers, which can step you closer to solution faster. The wiki Louis provide is good. If you want a generic explaination, consider:

```
2^1 * 2^1 = 2^2
2^2 * 2^2 = 2^4
2^4 * 2^4 = 2^8
...
```

This works great for powers of two. However I found it fun to play with non powers of two. So if I wanted 2^13 how could I do this?

```
2^1 * 2^1 = 2^2
2^1 * 2^2 = 2^3
2^3 * 2^3 = 2^6
2^6 * 2^6 = 2^12
2^12 * 2^1 = 2^13
```

The above example is to show that you don't have to play with only squares. If you play with this some, with various powers, you'll find that you can sometimes do better than just using powers of 2... its a fun math problem to play with.